# Making a mirror from Ubuntu Server repository doubt

Tags: wget, repository, mirror

Recently I bought an Orange Pi 2G IoT (this little SoC is really great!). I installed the Ubuntu Server and managed to connect to it through the serial port and I could even update the system (only apt-get update) and install some packages, but here's the little problem:
I would like to install packages offline (in my house I do not have an internet connection) and I tried to download the [repository](http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports/) but it only lets me download about 9 megabytes and don't even start with the "[pool](http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports/pool/)" files where (I think) reside the packages, it only make a list of the files in that repo and download some of the "index.html" but nothing more.

I am using a PC with Debian Jessie amd64, I situate in a folder in a NTFS partition (check that I have enough space) and I have tried to mirror the repository from the console using the `wget` command, with the following syntax:

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --show-progress --recursive --wait=5 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports/
```

Could someone with a better idea help me to download the repo to use it offline?

Comment: `wget`respects the `robots.txt` file when crawling recursively through web sites. You can override this behaviour with `-e robots=off` (see https://codenimbus.com/2010/08/02/override-robots-txt-with-wget/)

Comment: Yeap, I see the robots.txt "disable" many of the folder to download (recursively?)...thanks for giving the quick questions...let my try

Comment: That seems to work flawlessly!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` respects the robots.txt file when crawling recursively through web sites. You can override this behaviour with `-e robots=off`
More info [here](https://codenimbus.com/2010/08/02/override-robots-txt-with-wget/)

Thanks to @ridgy

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using `debmirror` instead of tryign to use wget since things won't all be linked, etc.

Here's the script I use to run `debmirror` note that you'll want to change the architecture, section, release, etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Architecture (i386, powerpc, amd64, etc.)
arch=i386,amd64

# Section (main,contrib,non-free)
section=main,multiverse,universe,restricted,partner

# Release of the system (squeeze,lenny,stable,testing,etc)
release=xenial,xenial-backports,xenial-proposed,xenial-security,xenial-updates,yakkety,yakkety-backports,yakkety-proposed,yakkety-security,yakkety-updates,zesty,zesty-backports,zesty-proposed,zesty-security,zesty-updates,artful,artful-updates,artful-security,artful-proposed,artful-backports

# Server name, minus the protocol and the path at the end
server=us.archive.ubuntu.com

# Path from the main server, so http://my.web.server/$dir, Server dependant
inPath=/ubuntu

# Protocol to use for transfer (http, ftp, hftp, rsync)
proto=http

# Directory to store the mirror in
outPath=/storage/mirrors/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

logfile=ubuntu-mirror.log-`date +%m-%d-%Y`

# Start script

debmirror -a $arch \
--no-source \
--slow-cpu \
--i18n \
--md5sums \
--progress \
--passive \
--verbose \
-s $section \
-h $server \
-d $release \
-r $inPath \
-e $proto \
$outPath 

# pull in all the Release.gz etc. stuff
for i in `echo $release | sed s/\,/\ /g`
do
     rsync -avrt rsync://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$i $outPath/dists
done

# fix Translation files
cd $outPath/dists
for i in `find ./ -iname Translation-en.gz`
    do nn=`echo $i | sed s/\.gz//g`
    zcat $i > $nn
done
```

Comment: Wow! This script seems to be very useful! Let me modify and try it! Thanks!!!!